# Flutter - Multiple HTTP Requests to the same JSON

Tags: json, rest, flutter

I have this API where go to fetch data. 
For each "date" I have a JSON Object.
What I want to do is fetch objects from let's say 5 years and get them on the same final JSON http response.
So I don't have to display only a day at the time.

```dart
Future<List<Schedule>> getFromEspnSchedule(String sport) async {
  final url = 'http://myserver.com/api/$date'; //the $date would be e.g. 2010, 2011, 2012, ...
  final response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    return jsonResponse.map((data) {
      return new Schedule.fromJson(data);
    }).toList();
  } 
}
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If your API returns just a single Schedule object, you need to modify your method to get a single element.

```
Future<Schedule> getFromEspnSchedule(String sport) async {
  final url = 'http://myserver.com/api/$date';
  final response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Schedule.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    // make sure you return API error here
  }
}
```

After you do this, you can go ahead and chain this into multiple calls made at the same time to achieve getting the data faster:

```
List<Schedule> responseList = await Future.wait([
  getFromEspnSchedule('football'),
  getFromEspnSchedule('volleyball'),
  getFromEspnSchedule('basketball'),
  getFromEspnSchedule('chess'),
]);

// responseList objects are listed the same way they are called above.
Schedule footballSchedule = responseList[0];
Schedule volleyballSchedule = responseList[1];
Schedule basketballSchedule = responseList[2];
Schedule chessSchedule = responseList[3];
```